# Swiper.js fails to inject the correct number of slides

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Also, the arrow navigation doesn't work. Here's the offending code on the [client site](https://badgerandcrow.com):

```
<!------------------------ PORTFOLIO ----------------------------------->
<script src="node_modules/swiper/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<script>
    const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
    
    direction: 'horizontal',
    loop: true,
    centeredSlides:true,
    

    // observer
    observer: true,
  observeParents: true,

  // If we need pagination
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
  },

  // Navigation arrows
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },

  // Default parameters
  slidesPerView: 3,
  spaceBetween: 10,
  // Responsive breakpoints
  breakpoints: {
    // when window width is >= 320px
    320: {
        initialSlide:2,
      slidesPerView: 2,
      spaceBetween: 20
    },
    // when window width is >= 480px
    480: {
        initialSlide:2,
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 30
    },
    // when window width is >= 640px
    640: {
        initialSlide:2,
      slidesPerView: 3,
      spaceBetween: 40
    }
  }
})
</script>

<div id="portfolio" class="dark portfolio-container" >
    <div class="inner">

        <h1>Portfolio</h1>

        <div class="swiper">
            <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="portfolio-img" src="assets/img/paintcity.png"/></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="portfolio-img" src="assets/img/paintersplus.png"/></div>
              <div class="swiper-slide"><img class="portfolio-img" src="assets/img/chc.png"/></div>
              <!--<div class="swiper-slide"><img class="portfolio-img" src="assets/img/placeholder.png"/></div>-->
            </div>

          <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

          <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
          <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
          <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I expect the three slides "Paint City", "Painters Plus" and "CHC" to all appear in the Portfolio section, but only one appears, which is the problem.

The Swiper [documentation](https://swiperjs.com/get-started#initialize-swiper) indicates we should adjust the slidesPerView value for the applicable breakpoints but I've done that and it has no effect.